# Replace last word in a string if it is 2 characters long using regex

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I am trying to replace last word of a string if it is 2 characters long using regex.  I used `[a-zA-Z]{2}$` but it is finding last 2 characters of string.  I don't want to replace the last word if it is not exactly 2 characters long, how can I do it?

Comment: Do Java regular expressions support word boundary \b?  `\b[a-zA-Z]{2}$`

Comment: @space Yes, they do. It's also `\b`. Java uses a syntax similar to Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to match a word boundary (`\b`) before the two letters:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

This will match any two Latin letters that appear at the end of a string, as long as they are not preceded by a 'word' character (which is a Latin letter, digit, or underscore).

In case you want to replace the word even if it is preceded by a digit or underscore, you might want to use a lookbehind assertion, like this:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

Answer (score 3):

`\\b\\w\\w\\b$` (regex in java flavor)

should work as well

Edit: in fact `\\b\\w\\w$` should be enough. ([or `\b\w\w$` in non-java flavor.. see demo link](http://regex101.com/r/sS1jN0))

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
[^\p{Alpha}]\p{Alpha}{2}$
```

Use `Alnum` instead if digits count as words. This does, however, fail if the entire string is only two characters long.